# Navision SSRS the IIF executes Else when it is TRUE?

Tags: image, reporting-services, report, navision

(rewrote of the problem)

I have trouble to display an image in the footer. The issue is, I try to convert an image from the DB to a Base64 String. In case of get an image is is working, but if in the db is a null value the Textfield displays #ERROR.

```
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Company_Picture.Value), "", Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!Company_Picture.Value))
```

I expected the else tree isn't executed in the case of IsNothing = True. But in the Report the TextField displays always #ERROR, if there is no image.

Solution is:

```
Public Function Base64String(ByVal img() as byte)
  if not isNothing(img) then
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(img)
  end if
  Return ""
end function
```

Thanks to all :-)

--- first try to cover my problem but it don't hit the main problem exact enougt ---

I have in the Report Code part
Shared Data1 as Object

```
Public Function GetData(Num as Integer, Group as integer) as Object
if Group = 1 then
   Return Cstr(Choose(Num, Split(Cstr(Data1),Chr(177))))
End If
End
```

and the same to set the data.

In the DB I have a image stored as blob. The direct displaying in the Report is working.
Now I have to show the image in footer of the report. I have made a Table and inside of one cell I use the hidden Expression to insert the Image to the object.

Here is now the issue. I try to make it with

```
Code.SetData(IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!CompanyPicture.Value, "DataSet_Result")) = TRUE, "", Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!CompanyPicture.Value) + Chr(177), 1)
```

The report crashes now on this expression, because the Hidden Expression can't be NULL. I do not understand, why from the IIF the else tree is executed. The IsNothing works correct and gives me True.

Any ideas what I can do, if the Image is Null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the comments in @Schlaagi's answer. IIF always evaluates both the true and false outcome so it will fail unless you accommodate this properly.

I don't know what the SetData function does and it's been a while since I've used Convert.ToBase64String but have a look at this and see if it makes sense.

```
=Code.SetData(
    Convert.ToBase64String(
                            IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CompanyPicture.Value, "DataSet_Result"),
                                "",
                                Fields!CompanyPicture.Value + Chr(177))
                            )
                            , 1
            )
```

Comment: Hi,
Sorry I don't hit the nutshell of the problem. Mainly I have trouble with the Convert of the image in the case of a null value. To day I see, the Convert need a Byte as input and not a string as I wrote. I changed the way to a code function and use a normal working if
Here is the code for others with the same issue:
`
Public Function ToBase64String(ByVal image() as byte)
  if not isNothing(image) then
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(image)
  end if
  Return ""
end function
`

Thanks for helping to find a new point of view to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I have to say is a style thing: I would never check if something equals true. Just write `IIf(isNothing(...), "", ...)`.

Secondly, you only check if the first entry in your dataset is not nothing, but call the convert method for every entry in your dataset. So if your dataset has for example two entries where the first is not nothing but the second is, you will get problems when evaluating the expression for this second entry.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I didn't have the multiple calls in mind. The = True Part comes from a original Microsoft report. Next time I will work without it.